# using marker in condition in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have one problem. I am plotting graph using stem function. And my problem is that in variable *values* there are many zero values. And they make red line under my plotted graph. Is here any possibility how to dont make a marker when value is zero? Thank you.

```
keys = list(dictionary.keys())
values = list(dictionary.values())
plt.stem(keys,values,'-ro')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about matplotlib, but maybe you can just [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) out the zero values before plotting.

Comment: So maybe something like `filtered = filter(lambda x: x[1]!=0, dictionary.items())`.

Comment: @Hassan Or a dict comprehension, which is what I used (disclaimer: I'm not totally matplotlib savvy either)

Comment: @matsjoyce Yeah that might be better. +1 looks like you got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it (I don't know if it is the matplotlibic way):

- First filter out the zero values
- Split the format into two keywords, to stop the bottom circle from being plotted
- Plot it

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
dictionary = {i: random.choice([0] * 100 + list(range(100))) for i in range(100)}
new_dict = {i: j for i, j in dictionary.items() if j}
keys = list(new_dict.keys())
values = list(new_dict.values())

plt.stem(keys, values, markerfmt='ro', linefmt='-r')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]